# c++ translate ostream operator to function call

Tags: c++, boost-phoenix, boost-lambda

I feel there should be a single liner with `boost::phoenix` that would let me stream an object having a member function `...::stream_to(std::ostream&)` with `<<` syntax. Something like this:

```
struct x { void stream_to(std::ostream&); }
LOG_INFO << MAGIC_SOMETHING(x);
```

But struggling to find that `MAGIC_SOMETHING(...)`. Am specifically interested in a solution that won't require me doing a forwarding marker struct and ostream operator for it.

Comment: That can't be done. The problem is ADL. Your best bet is a wrapper (e.g. `stream(x)` that returns an IO manipulator to invoke `stream_to`.

Comment: (I'm assuming there is no common base class for the structs implementing `stream_to`)

Comment: @sehe - no common base class. One other example is to stream `boost::ptree::write_xml(...)` directly into the logger stream without intermediate temporaries (`write_xml` takes stream as one of arguments).

Comment: Yeah, just write a manipulator.